# How to download file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file, download

I`ve no experience with PowerShell and never worked with it before.

That`s why I would like to ask for help and how it is possible to download the resources, i.e. the slide deck from https://mymbas.microsoft.com/sessions/74724013-e5cb-4606-a210-88089a2c8fd2?source=sessions

Downloading and unzipping the zip folder is no problem but I just don`t know what to do afterwards.

What do I have to type in the PowerShell script?

Thank you very much for any advice and help!

Comment: Why are you downloading the files in the first place if you don't know what to do with them?

Comment: I would like to get the slide deck. I didn`t know that you have to use PowerShell when clicking on Download Resources.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting" the slide deck? If you've already downloaded the zip file to your computer then you already "have it".

Comment: Really?! And "where" is it saved?

Comment: I mean it`s obviously not in the zip folder... there I only have the README and Download-Resources files.

Answer (score 0):

Exemple

```
$url = "https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.0/npp.7.Installer.exe"
$output = "C:\admintools\npp.7.Installer.exe"
$start_time = Get-Date

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. And what do I have to do with it? Or what do I have to do with Notepad++ afterwards?

Comment: Replace the assigned value to `$url` with your link. Replace the value assigned to `$output` with the name and location where you want to put the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn`t work. I get an empty file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).